# How to fill a Table View in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have written this code:

```
//Basic methods
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.DevicesTableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self,forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    self.DevicesTableView.dataSource = self

}


var array = ["one","two"]

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return array.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell: UITableViewCell! = self.DevicesTableView
        .dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell!

    cell.textLabel!.text = self.array[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

So the code works pretty well and shows me the tableview filled with:

Row1 "One"
Row2 "Two"

But how can I fill the TableView not at the beginning of my program but anytime else? I tried to call the methods below in an other function that viewDidLoad but it doest't work... why?

`self.DevicesTableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self,forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
 self.DevicesTableView.dataSource = self`

EDIT:

I would like to display an array which isn't initialized at the beginning of my program. It contains some BLE devices after the user searched for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its very simple

1. Update your data in your array
2. Then reload your tableview by using
   your_tableview.reloadData()

Ex:

```
var array = ["one","two","Three","Four"] // your array will take no.of.row in section
DevicesTableView.reloadData()
```

Answer (score 0):

Table views have a `reloadData` method which does what you want.