# Adding rows to tableview with a button

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode7

I want to make a tableview with a button in the upper corner. I want the button to add one more row to a tableview, so you can add a image to the cell or text. 
I have search over the internet but I have not found an answer.

Here is the source code:

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var imageArray = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Reccept") as UITableViewCell!

        let imageView = cell.viewWithTag(2) as! UIImageView!
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: imageArray[indexPath.row])

        return cell

    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return imageArray.count


    }


}
```

Comment: what did you try, where is the button's action ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of reload tableview, you should use `beginUpdates()` and `endUpdates()` for tableview.It would be much better approach..

First of all append data in your tableview array on button click

```
    Yourarray.append("image data")
```

Then update your table and insert new row

```
    // Update Table Data
    tblname.beginUpdates()
    tblname.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([
        NSIndexPath(forRow: Yourarray.count-1, inSection: 0)
        ], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
    tblname.endUpdates()
```

Comment: Thank you, where is the "reload tableview"? And also "tableview.it". Thanks for all the help :)

Comment: You don't need to reload tableview because begin and end updates just reload one cell..so no need to reload whole table....:)

Answer (score 1):

```
extend array by inserting the upcoming value suppose you have
var array: [String] = ["Iphone4", "Iphone5", "Iphone6"]
//all the table functions here which are boiler plate//
then
var newValue = textbox.text
array.append = newValue
tablewview.reloadData()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

1. Change your imageArray as mutable array cos that can append/update
   your array
2. Update your image in your imageArray at button action
3. Reload your table view at the button action

EX:

```
var imageArray:NSMutableArray=NSMutableArray()

@IBAction func buttonaction(sender:AnyObject)
{
  imageArray.addObject("Your image data")
  your_tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: If you have any doubt pls ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32799098/how-to-fill-a-table-view-in-swift/32799664#32799664

Comment: you don't need the mutable array. you can append directly in swift

Comment: @William, Yes you are right. Thanks 'imageArray.append("your_image_data")'

Comment: Thanks for all the awnswr, really aprichiate it:)

Answer (score 0):

**Instead of Table reloading, We can use beginUpdates and endUpdates**

**For SWIFT 3**

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
 tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: yourArray.count-1, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
 tableView.endUpdates()
```

**FOR SWIFT 4 and 5**

```
 answerTable.beginUpdates()
 answerTable.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row:Yourarray.count-1, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
        answerTable.endUpdates()
```

Answer (score 0):

**For Swift 5 and above:**

First append the array list for content of tableView rows.

Then add this line to the press button function:

```
tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: array.count-1, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
```